# How to add nodes to my private network?

Tags: stellar-core, private-network

If I have started a private network on my local machine, it will be running only one node. If I want to add few more nodes to it, how will I do it?

I am planning to use some AWS ec2 instances as nodes. How do I connect to the private network already running on my first system.

I have no knowledge in networking, please help me figure this out.